# nested div isn't visible in firefox, but visible in chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, ionic-framework

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.. in chrome we have a bunch of div tags that contain images.. overlayed an `<svg>`..

```
<svg class="canvass graph-bg">
    <svg>
        STUFFF
    </svg>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        STUFF
    </div>
</svg>
```

in Firefox they are not working at all, unless I un-nest the div

```
<svg class="canvass graph-bg">
    <svg>
        STUFFF
    </svg>
</svg>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
    STUFF
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think div is an accepted child for svg ... Chrome is probably ignoring your top level svg tag- but still that's wrong.

Comment: do you have a citation for that ?  I genuinely would like to learn what's proper

Comment: Allowed elements http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElement

Comment: NB: character data are not allowed in SVG element in "real" SVG context either. SVG in HTML5 is more permissive, but you definitely should not abuse that. Elements allowing text content in SVG are`text`, `tspan`, `a` and `textPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed after I pulled the `<div>` out of the `<svg>` element, which was a big no no thanks to help.

now we have

```
<svg class="canvass graph-bg">
    <svg>
        STUFFF
    </svg>
</svg>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
    STUFF
</div>
```